# How can I make body without inheriting from other defined View in SwiftUI, How apple done this at first place?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I like to study and learn about creation of View without using inheriting, for example for showing my goal, I made a new type View called **Color2**, it works as expected, but in the fact it inheriting from well defined Color, So if I want make Color2 stand alone and not inheriting from anything I must create or return **body**, otherwise **Color2** would not be compiles by SwiftUI! It is more like the old question of ***Which Came First, the Chicken or the Egg?***

How could Apple make the **Color** stand alone at first place or even exist? the time that Apple was making Color View, they should also thought about body of Color! But Apple is just creating Color, they could not be able even inheriting like i did in code! **because there is no Color view to be get inherit!!!**

So the **question/problem** is how can I return **body** without having a **reference/defined** View that conforms to View ? (See! I want create Egg without having Chicken)

**This down code working and they are JUST pseudocode:**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        Color2.red
        
    }
}
```

---

```
enum Color2 { case red, black }
```

---

```
extension Color2: View {

    public var body: some View {

        switch self {
        
        case Color2.red: Color.red      // <<: Here: how can I return a View if I want not using defined View! 
        case Color2.black: Color.black  // <<: Here: how can I return a View if I want not using defined View!
 
        }
    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question/problem is how can I return body without having a reference/defined View that conforms to View ?

You can't.

Here's what you do, as a **user** of SwiftUI:

- You make types that conform to `View` by implementing the `body` method.
- You create instances of types that conform to `View` and pass them to functions or return them from functions.

Here's what you **don't** do:

- You don't ask a `View` for its `body`.

The SwiftUI framework asks a `View` for its `body`. You never do.

The trick is that SwiftUI doesn't **always** ask a `View` for its `body`.

SwiftUI knows about some specific, “primitive” `View` types. When SwiftUI needs to render (or lay out) a primitive `View`, it recognizes that the `View` is a primitive type and handles it specially, **without** asking the primitive `View` for its `body`.

A `View` type is primitive if its `Body` is `Never`. How can I be sure of this? Because it's **impossible** to return a value of type `Never`! There are no such values. So, if a `View`'s `body` returns `Never`, I know that SwiftUI can't possibly ask that `View` for its `body`, so SwiftUI **must** treat that `View` differently than a “normal” `View`.

For example, `Text`, `Image`, and `Color` are all SwiftUI primitives:

```
  1> import SwiftUI
  2> Text.Body.self
$R0: Text.Body.Type = Never
  3> Image.Body.self
$R1: Image.Body.Type = Never
  4> Color.Body.self
$R2: Color.Body.Type = Never
```

On the other hand, `Rectangle` is not a primitive, but its `body` returns an undocumented primitive:

```
  5> Rectangle.Body.self
$R3: Rectangle.Body.Type = _ShapeView<Rectangle, ForegroundStyle>
  6> _ShapeView<Rectangle, ForegroundStyle>.Body.self
$R4: _ShapeView<Rectangle, ForegroundStyle>.Body.Type = Never
```

You can't implement your own primitive `View` type because you don't have access to the SwiftUI implementation details that recognize and handle primitive `View` types.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this: **import SwiftUI, Color.Body.self** then xcode complain that **are not allowed at top level**, So where you find those codes? If we are not allowed run those code why they are exist?

Comment: I ran my examples in the Swift REPL: `xcrun swift` from the command line. You could also use a Playground to test.

Comment: So In English Apple says and allow us to create View from the already defined Views by itself, in other word, we are allowed creating Views from Views, but we cannot define a brand new View like I tried. is that right to say?

Comment: I got my answer thanks a lot, My last question about the topic! I think also we are not allowed play with primitives, or even defining our custom primitive as user of Xcode/SwiftUI, and this locked down and only allowed for apple itself, is it right?

Comment: You cannot define your own primitive `View` types. You can only compose existing `View` types.

Answer (score 1):

Everything has to start somewhere. So you can either start with a View and compose, as in

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-and-compose-custom-views

Or you can wrap a UIView, as in

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui

To ask for a lower level would be to drop down to the pixel level of the screen with no framework at all, and that makes no sense. You are the *user* of a framework, not the *author* of a framework.

Comment: Then with your answer you are literally saying that SwiftUI is nothing more than a wrapped UIView?! let me put in this way: If we want create a View, we should use a defined View in SwiftUI or Wrap a UIView, with that said then every thing in SwiftUI is just a Wrapped UIView, from Color to Text, from VStack to Circle? because there is no Color View to reference it! or there is no Text View to reference it, and so on . .

Comment: No, I’m not saying that at all.

Comment: yes, you are saying that, you said there is 2 ways to create Views in SwiftUI! 1- using defined View 2- using wrapped UIView. think about this: Apple wants create and build Color View for us to use it in SwiftUI, ok? then Apple just has the wrapped UIView option to make it possible! because Apple cannot reference to Color View in SwiftUI, because it is not exist!