# Could I create my view structure without apple's primitives (Text, Image, Button, etc.) or derivative views?

Tags: swiftui

I try to figure out, how could I build my structure that realized View protocol without the composition of different views?

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // code without apples's views and derivatives
    }
}
```

If I could not, explain to me why, please.

Comment: You could build it out of UIViewRepresentables, or Path, but why? That would be like making text in UIKit via CAShapeLayer…

Comment: No, you cannot. See interface contract for `protocol View` - "Assemble the view's body by combining one or more of the primitive views provided by SwiftUI". So it is explicitly documented.

Comment: Could you explain to me, how primitives are made? Where could I find source codes of primitives?

Comment: There is no way provide a View that conform to View protocol without using SwiftUI build in primitives! Your question could be also asked as: How can I define a custom primitive! Which I think is not possible!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make body without inheriting from other defined View in SwiftUI, How apple done this at first place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728000/how-can-i-make-body-without-inheriting-from-other-defined-view-in-swiftui-how-a)

Comment: @swiftPunk No need to be so harsh. You asked basically the same question on March 21 of this year.

Comment: @robmayoff: What about you are talking? I really do not understand it!  It would be nice to show me or tell me that how you feel that I was harsh! Also I did not say he made bad question, because that was my question as you said.

Comment: @robmayoff: I never thought that way that I know more or better or harshing some one! All I do here is just learning and trying give back the helps that I received! Also big fan of your answer's and helps.